# Passing data between components with input and output

Tags: angular

So I'm new to angular two and i've looked at several tutorials trying to figure out how to do this and I can't get it to work. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

So I'm trying to pass a boolean value from one component to another, which will trigger an animation with ng-class. The event happens in the child component. I need the parent to respond.

Child component:

```
export class DefaultRouteViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() compare: boolean = false;
  @Output() compareEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(public _menu: MenuService) {}

  toggleCompare () {
    this.compare = !this.compare;
    this.compareEvent.emit({
       value: this.compare
    })
  }
```

Parent component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div class="app-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'hide-app' : hideApp}" (hideApp)="hideAppChange($event);" (compareEvent)="hideAppChange($event)"></div>',
  directives: NgClass, DefaultRouteViewComponent],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hideApp: Boolean;

  constructor() {}

  hideAppChange(event) {
     console.log(event);
  }
}
```

I feel like the problem is in the parent component template. I'm not sure though. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What is the selector of your child component and its usage in parent template?

Comment: `selector: 'app-default-route-view',` is the selector. The parent is the header. The child is just a template for the route.

Comment: Not sure if `Output` is working in that case then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible duplicate [Passing @Input and subscribing to @Output while navigating to a Route in Angular 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558497/passing-input-and-subscribing-to-output-while-navigating-to-a-route-in-angular)

If you need to communicate between Parent and child routed components you may use [Bi Directional service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

you may see similar [implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733519/angular2-pass-value-from-parent-route-to-child-route/38733668#38733668)

Answer (score 1):

The 'compareEvent' event binding needs to be placed as an attribute on the selector for the child component in the parent component's html.

So in the parent component template html you need something like:

```
<app-default-route-view (compareEvent)="hideAppChange($event)">
</app-default-route-view>
```

Hope that helps!